# iterate through a list of item and save it

Tags: python

what's a better why to iterate through this list of item and save it

```
if cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        date = str(row[0])
        servicelevel = str(row[1])
        power = str(row[2])
        rebootime = str(row[3])
        result = str(row[4])
        result_two = str(row[5])
        moredata = str(row[6])
        data_Rows.append({'date': date, 'servicelevel': servicelevel, 'power': power, 'rebootime': rebootime,
                           'result': result, 'result_two': result_two, 'moredata': moredata})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary of field names to row indexes. For example:

```
cursor = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
fields = { 'date' : 0 , 'servicelevel' : 1, 'power' : 2 }

data_Rows = []
for row in cursor:
    data_Rows.append({ f : str(row[v]) for f, v in fields.items() })

print(data_Rows)
```

Output:

```
[{'power': '3', 'servicelevel': '2', 'date': '1'}, {'power': '6', 'servicelevel': '5', 'date': '4'}]
```

Comment: what does f and V stand for? also why is it backward? starting from power?

Comment: @DavidShapero `f, v in fields.items()` successively assigns the keys and values from `fields` into those variables, so in the first iteration `f = 'date', v = 0`, then in the second `f = 'servicelevel', v = 1` etc. I've used `f` and `v` as shorthand for `field name` and `row value index`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```py
if cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        data_Rows.append({'date': str(row[0]), 'servicelevel': str(row[1]), 'power': str(row[2]), 'rebootime': str(row[3]),
                           'result': str(row[4]), 'result_two': str(row[5]), 'moredata': str(row[6])})
```

Comment: Thank you, if let's say I want to access date afterward what should I do?> data_Rows.get("date") or data_Rows["date"] ?

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the column headers with each row to create a dict for each row with the `dict` constructor:

```
headers = 'date', 'servicelevel', 'power', 'rebootime', 'result', 'result_two', 'moredata'
data_Rows.extend(dict(zip(headers, map(str, row))) for row in cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in cursor:
    d = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(['date', 'servicelevel', 'power', 'rebootime', 'result', 'result_two', 'moredata']):
        d[v] = str(row[i])
    data_Rows.append(d)
```